# Bamboo and multi module projects

Tags: maven, bamboo

I use Atlassian Bamboo and am getting circular dep problems when it runs my maven module.

Consider I have three modules

```
model
  dto
  dao

logic
  dto
  components

business
  dto
  service
```

When I run this from my cmd line it will run

```
model dao
model dto
logic dto
business dto
logic components
business service
```

which is correct and the way I have set up the dependencies. Bamboo on the other hand will only consider the top level modules so it see a circular dependency between logic and business.

The real scenario is a bit more complicated but hopefully this explains it well enough.

Is there any way to make bamboo run and consider each module separately rather than at top level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create multiple plans for each of the module like you run in command line.Then you can use dependent blocking mechanism to each plan to build one after the other. you may get help from [1] how to use dependent planning strategy for that.
1. https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Dependency+blocking+strategies